# How to Retrieve CaseTeamMember and CaseTeamMemberRole in SFDX project?

Tags: salesforcedx, case, case-teams

I have added the Case Team Member Role in the sandbox and now trying to retrieve this in the SFDX project in VS CODE.

I tried org explorer, Change set and SFDX source retrieve command but nothing is showing these objects.

Please help with how to retrieve this info.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are unable to see it as it is unsupported metadata [Unsupported metadata](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm)